# WPF repeated image background

Tags: wpf, background

i using C# and WPF building my project. In my application, i used a  small size of image(25x25) as my application background. I found some example from the internet and when i try it, the background of my application is like imageA. But what i wish to do is like my background will be like the imageB. Any one know how to make it like the imageB?

my WPF code snippet:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0.8,0.8,0.1,0.1"  AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Image Source="/Wpf_Customer;component/bg.jpg"></Image>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <RadioButton Content="Graph" Name="dsad" FontSize="15" ></RadioButton>

</Grid>
```

imageA:

[image]

imageB:

[image]

**EDITED:**

imageC:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Try it

```
 <ImageBrush x:Key="SimpleBitmap" ImageSource="Assets\BitmapImage.png" TileMode="FlipY"      Stretch="Uniform"AlignmentY="Top" Viewport="0,0,10,10" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
```

Where BitmapImage Width = 10, and BitmapImage Height = 10

Comment: Your solution push me to right direction, but with little change for me:
`<ImageBrush AlignmentY="Top"
                        ImageSource="/Resources/Images/pattern-notebook.png"
                        Stretch="None"
                        TileMode="FlipY"
                        Viewport="0,0,10,10"
                        ViewportUnits="Absolute" />`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to set `Stertch` property of your image element to `UniformToFill`?

**UPDATE:** Yeah, it was lame, my bad... Actually, you have no need to use VisualBrush, if I correctly understood your task. This should be enough:

```
<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Wpf_Customer;component/bg.jpg"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

Comment: hm...i tried your method, the image was enlarged not repeated.

Comment: Isn't it what you want to get? :)

Comment: As I can see your `bg.jpg` contains gradient fill. You may understand it's not possible to stratch only gradient without affecting background pattern. Your pattern should to be flat to get nice tiling. If you want achieve stratching gradient fill above your pattern you should use for it overlaying component. I can help you with that too :)